Shred a bad HDD
Here is my situation, I am running a NAS with Synology Hybrid RAID (SHR) which I believe to be similar to RAID 1. One of the HDDs stopped working, I replaced it, everything's working and I did not lose any data.
The HDD that stopped working is still under warranty and I would like to send it back and get a new one. The problem, however, is the fact that none of my data was encrypted. I am a bit afraid of sending it, they refurbish it or something like that and they or the new user will have access to all my data.
Therefore, I am trying to erase all the data from the bad HDD before sending it to Seagate, the HDD brand. And here is where I am struggling.
I have one SATA to USB adapter that I used to connect the bad HDD to my linux machine. I run dmesg -w and got the following:
[ 1500.751823] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1500.950024] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0583, bcdDevice= 4.14
[ 1500.950029] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1500.950031] usb 1-5: Product: YzWy  Disk Device
[ 1500.950032] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: jack88888
[ 1500.950034] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: DD564198338A1
[ 1500.982268] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 1500.996612] scsi host3: uas
[ 1500.996843] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[ 1501.007424] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Shenzhen YongzhenWeiye    0414 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1501.009461] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1501.009738] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[ 1501.009741] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 1501.009879] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1501.009881] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 5f 00 00 08
[ 1501.010166] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1501.010184] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
[ 1501.010186] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of preferred minimum block size (4096 bytes)
[ 1501.058851] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk

So far so good, I open a new terminal and start shredding the data with shred /dev/sdb -v. However, after around 30 seconds (it varies), dmesg outputs this:
[ 1684.576773] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#22 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 1684.576778] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#22 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 1684.604907] scsi host3: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 1684.734218] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1684.935710] scsi host3: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success

The HDD is unresponsive and after a few seconds, I get:
[ 1945.138934] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 1945.139283] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 1945.139286] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 1945.139306] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=322s
[ 1945.139308] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 1945.139312] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 2
[ 1945.139731] device offline error, dev sdb, sector 2188672 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x8800 phys_seg 16 prio class 2
[ 1945.190646] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1945.474852] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK

Which disconnects/unmounts the HDD, and I lose access to it, exiting shred prematurely. The HDD is sometimes detected again and the cycle resumes.
I understand that this is the problem the HDD had in the first place but I was wondering if any of you would know of a way to either ignore these errors just to keep it mounted long enough for shred to finish, or maybe find a way to resume shred where it was the last time it run. I could then make it run whenever the HDD is detected again.
That way I could shred all my data and safely return the HDD for a replacement.
I am running Ubuntu 22 but also have a live SystemRescueCD image if that helps.
What do you think? Do you see a way of shredding my data without voiding the warranty on the bad HDD? Or should I just accept the loss and drill a hole in it?
Thank you in advance,
Grifo

If you're willing to drop some money on the problem, look at buying a degausser for somewhere around $100US. Writing your own tool like David G. suggested would work but I doubt any hardware changes will help since it is the disk electronics at fault.

I think the issue is going to be the failure mode.  If something is wrong with the electronics, it will probably keep failing everywhere.  If something has gone wrong in the media, it will fail whenever you involve the failing area.
In either case, I would recommend writing your own eraser designed to write some stuff, ensure it is synced, and record that area written.  And any time there are errors, skip over a lot.  Maybe even do occasional random jumps.  You might also need to do the writes slowly.  (Maybe the disk is overheating?)  In any case, I would record what worked and what failed, and eventually hope to get a large portion of the drive written.  I would write this to do one byte pattern at a time, and do multiple complete runs with different patterns.
ddrescue might make a good pattern for doing this.  At least, it might be worth looking at its logfile format.
